# Arrows pointing to data from label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a number of related time series I want to plot together. I am using `ggplot2`
Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
set.seed(0)
require(ggplot2)
id <- LETTERS[1:18]
appDates <- as.Date("2000-01-01", origin = '1970-01-01') + 1:10
appRate <- runif(18, 1,4)
appRank <- rank(-appRate - colSums(anorm))

anorm <- array(rnorm(18*11), c(11,18))
tempDf <-lapply(seq_along(appDates), function(x) data.frame(adate = appDates[x], group = 1:18, id = id, arate = appRate + colSums(anorm[1:(x+1),]), ranked = appRank))

tempDf <- do.call(rbind, tempDf)
ggplot(tempDf, aes(x = adate, y = arate, group = group, color = id)) + geom_line()
```

This is fine but I would like arrows going from the id labels to the relevant time series as it is hard to pick out a particular path with the colors being similar.

[image]

I have tried `directlabels' but I cant seem to quite get it

```
p <- ggplot(tempDf, aes(x = adate, y = arate, group = group, color = id)) + geom_line()
require(directlabels)
direct.label(p,list(last.points, hjust=0.8, vjust = 1))
```

[image]

A crude example done by hand of what I am sort of looking for

[image]

With the addition of final rankings I have added differing line thickness to aid identification.

```
p <- ggplot(tempDf, aes(x = adate, y = arate, group = group, color = id, size = ranked)) + geom_line()
p + scale_size(range=c(2.6, 0.4), guide=FALSE)+
       guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=seq(2.6,0.4, length.out = 18)[appRank])))
```

[image]

Comment: the `directlabels` version looks much better than the arrows, in my opinion; it's also easier to achieve programmatically.

Comment: Yes I realise the arrows will look pretty bad once they are all in. Maybe a change of color scheme may help. It is hard to pick out a timeseries as it stands.

Comment: @user1609452 Nice question. No matter what you do, 18 time series all plotted on top of each other are going to look ugly, but more importantly, it will be difficult to draw inference. In [a recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280468/data-visualization-in-r/17281228#17281228) I suggested that a user use a heat map to visualize multiple time series like these; might that not be appropriate in this case as well? It would be easy to tell the groups apart, and you could easily compare any group at different time points.

Comment: @nograpes thanks. The timeseries represent rankings at particular times. So if I could easily identify which series was which then I could see the ordering at a given point in time which is what is important in this case. I have updated my question and added different line thickness to make identification easier.

Comment: I'll supplement @nograpes that there is an inherent problem in having 18 distinct lines in a single plot. First, the average person cannot distinct between more than 6-7 qualitative colours. This means that colour coding 18 different lines makes it impossible to *easily* identify which line is which data. By adding line thickness to circumvent this problem, you are using a double-factor coding for a single category. In addition, with thicker lines for some lines you are implying these lines are more important.

Comment: @MrGumble interesting lets suppose the 18 variables were Bundesliga football teams. I had thought to have 4 groups top, mid upper, mid lower and bottom with 4 plots in a grid. Maybe this is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer your question exactly, I wanted to include some pictures of what I mean, so I put it in an answer.

If *rank* is really what you want to show, then I especially recommend the heat map. Except that instead of using the rate as the y-axis, you use the rank, and you use the rate as the fill color. Here is what I mean:

```
# I think your rank was broken -- but I might be missing something.
tempDf$real.rank<-unlist(by(tempDf$arate,tempDf$adate,rank)) 
ggplot(tempDf, aes(x = adate ,fill = arate, y = real.rank)) +   ]
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label=id),color='white')
```

[image]

If you really wanted to emphasize the change in rank, you could draw lines in between the letters:

```
ggplot(tempDf, aes(x = adate ,fill = arate, y = real.rank)) +   
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label=id),color='white') +
  geom_line(aes(group=id,color=id))
```

[image]

In either case, I think that you add an extra dimension of data with a heatmap, the rank itself, at the expense of making it more difficult to tell the exact rate.

Comment: Yes i really like that. I will try it on my dataset and see how it looks.